# filter data frame rows by the top quantitile of one of the multiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a data frame with multiIndex, and I only want to keep the subset records whose column values are in the top quantile in the level 0 index.

In the following example df, I want to keep the records whose column A values are on top 75% quantile per level 0 index. What's the pythonic way of doing it?

```
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']),
    np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 3), index=arrays, columns = ['A','B','C'])
```

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you mean?

```
df.groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).apply(lambda g: g[g.A >= g.A.quantile(0.75)])
```

[image]